# How would I use the same component arrangement for each instance of a sheet symbol?

Tags: pcb, altium, symbol, reuse

I'm designing a PCB using Altium. I am a beginner and I'm using sheet symbols to design 6 identical circuits.

Making a billion circuits with identical schematics is easy, but in order to make the PCB layout of each instance of the circuit also identical I have to repeatedly arrange the components in the exact same way manually.

Is there a way to avoid placing manually the components from each sheet symbol in an identical arrangement over and over?

Comment: I think you're asking how to panelize your design? Does that sound correct?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't have multiple circuits the same in a design. You'd have one, lay it out, then panelize it.

Comment: Are you talking about multiple identical circuits on the same PCB, or multiple identical PCBs (as in panelization)?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm talking about multiple identical sub-circuits on the same PCB. I want them all to have the same components and I want the components to be arranged in the same fashion for every sub-circuit.

Comment: Panelizing is for having multiple PCBs on one panel. You would not use it for portions of one PCB unless that PCB is entirely (or almost entirely) composed of the sub-circuits (if that makes sense). A potential advantage of that over using rooms is that you could edit the sub-circuit and the changes ripple through. It's mostly intended for making n-up boards that are all the same on one panel, but you *can* route between the boards (I don't think you get DRC or a schematic for that stuff though- perhaps I'm wrong on that).

Answer (score 4):

If you're making multiple instances of a portion of a layout, the best way (as far as I've found) is to put the replicated circuit in rooms (one copy in each room). In some circumstances you can use a repeat block on the schematic, in others it's more clear to lay out multiple similar blocks.

On the PCB design, you can lay out the parts in one room, then when you have it perfect, copy the room layout from the master to the other rooms (Design -> Rooms -> Copy Room Formats). It's quite powerful when used in conjunction with 'channels'.

[This](http://www.altium.com/files/altiumdesigner/s08/learningguides/tu0112%20creating%20a%20multi-channel%20design.pdf) Altium tutorial describes the schematic steps.

[This](https://www.ece.ufl.edu/sites/default/files/pictures/Module%2013%20-%20Classes%20and%20Rooms.pdf) Altium tutorial describes how the PCB steps.

You'll probably want to change the default designator scheme- it creates really long ugly designator strings. I prefer something like R1A R2A/R1B R2B for resistors R1 and R2 in channels A and B (might be sub-optimal if you needed more than 26 channels).

You can also use snippets.

Answer (score 1):

This video will help you. It's how learned how to do it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYgvRCrVeOI

The relevent bits start around 8mins on how to route one room, and then use the duplicate room feature within altium.